# Household chores scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, scheduling

### Backstory

So here's the thing. I live in the household of three and the eldest of us has grown tired of doing all the household chores by herself. We have tried making different schedules for tasks but there were **always** problems because either one of us was not at home and chores were left undone or someone felt that they were doing more work than others leading to resentment and unwillingness to complete a chore.

### Problem

Humans err, but computer programs are infallible, right? The idea is that a computer program could be used to fairly distribute the chores to be done so that no one can feel like he or she is doing more work. I am trying to come up with an algorithm that would distribute the chores conforming to these criteria:

- It should evenly distribute the chores in the long term with probability of roughly 1/3.
- It should return an ordered list of people so if the first one is unavailable, the second can complete it.
- It should avoid scheduling multiple chores per person on a same day.
- It should avoid scheduling the same chore to the same person for multiple consecutive times.
- It should be deviation-tolerant. If chore was not done by the scheduled person, it should still remain fair provided that the actual person who did the chore was fed back.
- It should work with different chores with different frequencies (you need to do the dishes every day but only clean the bathroom once a week, ...)

My question is: **What would be the best/coolest/fairest way to implement this algorithm?**
(ridiculously oversophisitcated solutions are appreciated :D)

---

### What have I tried?

I figured a simple way to implement such an algorithm would be to define a cost table for different criteria and then just use the weighted random numbers to select the person but I think this will not be fair in the long term (it really has to limit towards 1/3 per person or it won't be accepted :)).

Comment: This is your opportunity to learn Prolog :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem consists out of 2 parts:

1) **Define the score function.** How do you define fair, efficient, ...? What is the trade-off between them? There are [different techniques](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3034) to do the trade-offs:

- score weighting, for example: 1 times (unevenly distribution) == 5 times (a multiple chore on a day)
- score levels, for example: (unevenly distribution) always outranks (a multiple chore on a day)
- Pareto scoring: see Wikipedia

2) **Use an optimization algorithm to find the schedule (out of all possible schedules) with the highest score.** If your problem is NP-complete, then there is no such perfect algorithm out there. But there are very good ones none the less. I prefer to start with *First Fit Decreasing*, followed by *Tabu Search*.

For a complete, detailed overview of a similar example with implementing code, **follow [this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#cloudBalancingTutorial)**. Mentally replace the word `Computer` by `Person` and `Process` by `Chore`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it seems like your constraints are loose enough and that your algorithm won't need to scale up too much, so you should just be able to make an algorithm that forces a schedule to meet all of your criteria, and there are a ton of different ways to implement it.  Here are some random musings that might help get you started.

Suppose I have a list of chores to assign for a given day (but this should work for any period of time).  Each chore has a weight (how arduous people think it is or how long it takes or something).  Each chore has a name or is an instance of some class (so that we can tell that two bathroom cleans are the same chore and we won't be as likely to assign it to the same person twice).  I also have a list of all chores done by people in the past (including who actually did them rather than just who it was assigned to).

If you think want to distribute *chores* with probability 1/3, a simple way to do this would be to say:

```
while has_more_chores()
  randomize the order of the persons list
  foreach person:
    if (has_more_chores()):
      person.assign_chore()
```

which basically guarantees that each person has done as many chores as everyone else.  However, that wouldn't take weight into account.  If weight is important, it probably makes more sense to do

```
foreach chore:
  chore.choose_person()
```

Whether you are doing person.assign_chore() or chore.choose_person(), you will want to apply some sort of balancing function so that one person doesn't end up cleaning the bathroom all the time. You could use a modified exponential backoff to reduce the probability of getting a chore after having done it a bunch.

Maybe an easier way to approach the problem would be to randomly generate a zillion different person-chore schedules and disqualify any that don't meet your constraints (ie, same chore by one person multiple times in a row  or one person doing multiple chores in a day).

Answer (score 1):

You could try some sort of "funny money" economy, with prices and wages in credits, or luxury consumables, rather than real money, in the hope that an efficient market will emerge and provide the optimal solution.

If you *really* want something, complicated, consider the [Clarke Pivot rule in a Vickrey-Clarke-Groves auction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey%E2%80%93Clarke%E2%80%93Groves_auction). Here doing or not doing a household chore, or a batch of household chores, is a possible outcome to be bid for. You should find that the bank organising the auction runs a small profit, which it could redistribute to all as a festival when enough has accumulated.